# What are the applications of ant colony optimization algorithms?

Tags: applications, swarm-intelligence, ant-colony-optimization

I'm interested in ant colony optimization algorithms and bee algorithms,but I'm confused what are the applications of these algorithms

Can you suggest me some examples of applications can I work on?

Comment: Ant colony algorithms are used for path searching and routing if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first ant colony optimisation algorithm was introduced by [Marco Dorigo](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~mdorigo/HomePageDorigo/) in the report *Positive Feedback as a Search Strategy* (1991) and his PhD thesis *Optimization, Learning and Natural Algorithms* (1992). He's still one of the leading figures in the field of [swarm intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence) (having also written or co-written several papers and books). Another important person that contributed to ACO algorithms is [Luca Gambardella](http://people.idsia.ch/~luca/) (co-director of [IDSIA](http://www.idsia.ch/)).

There are several ACO algorithms. They are all based on the way real ants behave, that is, by leaving a substance called "pheromone" on the ground in order to communicate. More specifically, the amount of pheromone is associated with value (e.g. food): more pheromone means more value. (It should now be clear the reason behind the queues real ants form).

A list of ACO algorithms can be found at [http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~mdorigo/ACO/publications.html](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~mdorigo/ACO/publications.html#THIRD). For reproducibility, here's a (non-exhaustive) list:

- Ant System
- Elitist Ant System
- Ant-Q
- Ant Colony System
- Max-Min Ant System
- Rank-based Ant System
- ANTS
- Hyper Cube - ACO

ACO algorithms have been applied to **[combinatorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization)** and **[NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)** (e.g. the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)) problems. ACO algorithms are thus a collection of meta-heuristic and probabilistic algorithms (in the same family of [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)) to tackle often considered [intractable problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability). The [related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms#Applications) contains a more exhaustive section dedicated to the applications of these algorithms. ACO algorithms are often combined with [local search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) (like the 2-opt or 3-opt).

I would suggest you to start with the travelling salesman problem, which was the first application of these algorithms. You can have a look at the reference implementations at http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~mdorigo/ACO/aco-code/public-software.html, where you can also find software to solve specific tasks (not just the TSP, such as maximum clique problems).

Comment: that's very useful, thanks, but I'm looking for a new topic to apply this algorithm, any ideas ?

Comment: @HamzaDabjan Maybe you could look at some NP-complete problem that people have not yet tackled using ACO. See e.g. this list [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#NP-complete_problems).